# Atualizar database através de uma Cloud Function - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-functions

Vendo um tutorial da Jen Person, no canal do Firebase no youtube, eu escrevi uma função em javascript que é acionada quando um usuário do meu app faz upload de uma imagem no Firebase Storage. Essa função gera uma thumbnail (miniatura) da imagem e a guarda no Firebase Storage também. Meu problema é: Eu não sei muito javascript. Eu já tenho as URLs das imagens que estão no Storage, mas eu preciso atualizar os valores das respectivas childs no Firebase Database, sendo que preciso armazená-las no ID do usuário corrente, ou seja, o que fez o upload do arquivo. Dentro de cada ID do usuário eu tenho entre outros campos, os campos "image" e "thumb_image" que devem guardar a URL das suas imagens no Storage.

Aqui está meu código:

```
    exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
    const object = event.data
    const filePath = object.name
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop()
    const fileBucket = object.bucket
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
    const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${fileName}`
    const ref = admin.database().ref()
    const file = bucket.file(filePath)
    const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)$/, '$1thumb_$2')

    if(fileName.startsWith('thumb_')) {
        console.log('This file is already a thumbnail')
        return
    }

    if(!object.contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
        console.log('This is not an image to create thumbnail.')
        return
    }
    if (object.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
        console.log('There has been an image deletion event.')
        return
    }

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tempFilePath
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath)
        return spawn('convert',[tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath])
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Thumbnail created!')

        return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
            destination: thumbFilePath
        })
    }).then(() => {
        const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath)
        const config = {
            action: 'read',
            expires: '03-09-2491'
        }
        return Promisse.all([
            thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
            file.getSignedUrl(config)
        ])
    }).then(results => {
        const thumbResult = results[0]
        const originalResult = results[1]
        const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0]
        const fileUrl = originalResult[0]


       // Não sei o que fazer a partir daqui
    })
})
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?
Agradeço desde já.

Esta é a estrutura do meu Database:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui é em português amigo. Traduza a sua pergunta por gentileza.

Comment: @dvd Devidamente traduzido. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Só não esqueça de traduzir o título também.

Comment: Você pode postar a estrutura da sua base de dados? Vai nos ajudar a saber onde colocar a url

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Editei a postagem adicionando a estrutura da base de dados. O diretório Users está na raiz.